# Notation: Exponent of a group

Tags: gr.group-theory, notation

The *exponent* of a group $G$ is the least positive $n$ such that $g^n = e$ for all $g \in G$. This is obviously a sensible name for the concept.

A notational awkwardness arises however when the group $G$ is abelian and written additively. I find it grating to refer to the least positive $n$ such that $\forall g \in G$ $ng = e$ as the *exponent* because there is nothing going on that even looks like exponentiation.

Is there an alternate terminology that can be used in this situation?

Comment: I guess this is not accepting your frame of question, but my advice is to still say "exponent" (and perhaps commenting on the terminological infelicity). Doing anything else is complicating things needlessly.

Comment: @Ben: The word "period" is standard and is in most algebra books (I gave the example of Lang, only because it is the first book given by google books). Using "exponent" would be weird.  

Comment: I would use "annihilator", since an abelian group is, among other things, a $\mathbb Z$-module.

Comment: Either you're only ever considering abelian groups, in which case Theo's advice seems quite sensible, or you're mostly considering nonabelian groups but occasionally run across an abelian one.  In the latter case my advice is: write the group multipliciatively anyway!  That is think of Z/4 as g^x for x in Z/4 and g a formal generator.

Comment: Following Noah's suggestion, you can write $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ multiplicatively as $\mu_4(\mathbb{C})$, or formally as $\langle g \mid g^4 = 1\rangle$

Answer (score 9):

It is called period if the group is Abelian and the notation is additive, an Abelian group of period $n$: look [here (Lang's "Algebra")](http://books.google.com/books?id=Fge-BwqhqIYC&pg=PA42&dq=Abelian+groups,+period&hl=en&ei=VgzOTPmWKoHGlQeRoZWwBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Abelian%20groups%2C%20period&f=false)  . The period of an element $a$ (in the additive notation) is sometimes called the order of $a$. See, for example,  [Fuchs' classic book.](http://books.google.com/books?id=Vb38GspKia8C&pg=PA4&dq=Abelian+groups,+Fuchs,+group+of+finite+period,+element&hl=en&ei=kDDOTIrOEMTflgeaxLyXBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: It seems that for Lang only elements of groups have periods, and these are what most people call orders.

Comment: @Dylan: In the additive notation it is called "period" since 19-th century. 

Comment: The term "period" is commonly used in a different context; namely, the period of a subset S of an abelian group is the set of all group elements g such that S+g=S. (This is also called the *stabilizer* of S.) Thus, the period of the whole group is the group itself! I myself use the term "exponent" without experiencing any moral inconvenience :-) 

Comment: @Seva: Serial killers don't have any moral problems also. As Dostoevsky used to say: "тварь дрожащая или право имею". Of course you have the right to call anything anyhow. 

Comment: @Mark: Sorry, but I find your comparison quite unappropriate, and your last remark pretty much irrelevant. Each of us can "call anything anyhow", but this trivial fact does not support the arguments of either side. 

Comment: @Seva: You suggest to replace the standard terminology used in classical books and huge number of papers by nonstandard one. Moreover you claim that it is "commonly used". As I said, you can do it if you wish, but you should not be surprised by negative, and sometimes not quite polite reaction. 

Comment: @Mark: you seem to do the common mistake of declaring "standard" what you are used to, and "non-standard" anything else. There **are** lots of books and papers using the term *period* the way I described; if you are not familiar with them, this does not mean that they do not exist. And yes, I am very much surprised with your "not quite polite" reaction, and above all, with your advocating of this reaction.

Comment: @Seva: I gave examples of two classic algebra books: Lang and Fuchs. The first is one of the standard text-books in general algebra (and has been such since the 70s, that is the 3d edition, I think) and the second is the standard book on Abelian groups. If you know any books of similar value which use your terminology, why don't you list them here. As far as politeness is concern, you are very lucky Lang cannot participate in this discussion. 

Comment: Please calm down everyone. This question is not important enough to warrant such strong emotions! 

Answer (score 2):

First, I appologise since this should rather be a comment (but I cannot yet comment).

Yet, in the process of reading this question and some of the linked material I got confused, and since I very frequently use the term exponent for abelian groups denoted additively, and know various people who do likewise, I am quite interested in this, too.

1. I looked at the linked content of Fuchs's book but I failed to locate the part that Mark Sapir is referring to. (I have no access to the book at the moment, and thus would be greatful for a precise quote of the relevant part.) 
   The only thing I found online is that 'periodic' is used a synonym for 'torsion', but no mention of period of a group.
2. Also in Lang I was unable to find the mentioned usage, it seems Dylan Moreland made the same experience. Indeed, it seems period of an element is used in Lang also when the notation is multiplicative.

Sorry, for this abuse of 'answer', but I would be grateful for clarification and did not know how to express this except via and 'answer'.